# probability question with more than one factor

Tags: probability

There are $5$ original paintings and $7$ copy paintings. There's an expert who knows an original from a copy with the probability of $\frac{5}{6}$. The expert is just now saying that the picture is an original. What's the probability of him being right?

I tried everything, $\frac{5}{12}$ orig $\frac{7}{2}$ fake and multiplying $\frac{5}{12}$ by $\frac{5}{6}$ but I can't reach a solution. It seems kind of harder than any other exercise.

Comment: It seems harder than other exercises because it requires the principle of "conditional probability," or the answers to questions like "What's the probability of A given the probability of B?" 

In this case, the question would be: "What is the probability that the painting is original *given that the expert says it is?"*

Check out Bayes' Rule, as Shane and Ross have referred to- you'll be able to figure this out pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  what is the probability that the painting is original and the expert says it is?  The and says you multiply.  Call it $A$. What is the probability that the painting is a copy and the expert says it is original? Call it $B$.  The total of these is the chance that the expert will declare a random painting original.  The chance that he is right, given that he declared the painting original is $\frac A{A+B}$

Comment: Ross is correctly proposing that you apply [Bayes' Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_rule). Problems like these are very typical applications of Bayes' rule.